# I cant run multiple user-defined functions that use PYAUTOGUI

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm currently having trouble setting up user defined functions that involve pyautogui.

I'm able to import functions from other .py files no worries however when i try to run one after another the second one does not actually take control of the mouse and keyboard.

sample code Below

```
def findProgram(point, taskbar_image):
    taskbar_image = r"file location"
    point = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(taskbar_image)
    point = pyautogui.center(point)
    pyautogui.moveTo(point, duration=.2)
    pyautogui.click()
    return

def findList(home, browser):
    home = (25, 35)
    browser = (45, 75)
    pyautogui.moveTo(home, duration=.2)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.moveTo(browser, duration=.2)
    pyautogui.click()
    return

findProgram(0, 0)

findList (0, 0)
```

When I run this (even without importing them into another file) the first function will action but the second will not. The process finishes with no errors. I'm very new to programming so apologies for any lack of clarity.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I tried with

```
def findProgram(point, taskbar_image):
    #taskbar_image = r"file location" #i don't have the image so i changed it with what it will give (pos)
    #point = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(taskbar_image)
    #point = pyautogui.center(point)
    point = (1,0)
    pyautogui.moveTo(point, duration=.2)
    pyautogui.click()
    return

def findList(home, browser):
    home = (25, 35)
    browser = (45, 75)
    pyautogui.moveTo(home, duration=.2)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.moveTo(browser, duration=.2)
    pyautogui.click()
    return

findProgram(0, 0)

findList (0, 0)
```

and it seems no problem,so maybe the problem is at image you give.

Two tip:
`Findprogram()` don't seem to need any parameter, as it get overwrite in first,second line of function, and so is `findlist()`